# Text file manipulation: Take data from text file and write a new text file with the data taken from the original file

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, read-write

I'm writing a program to manipulate some data in a text file. I'm supposed to take state ID, population, and school attendance, and poverty from a file that contains more information than these 4 and write them into a new text file. Then use this new text file to do some maths.
This is the original text file structure:
[image: This is the original text file structure]
I ran into errors in my code and would appreciate some help. To be specific the errors are index out of bounds and non-static method cannot be reference from this context.

Class to define data for extraction:
[image: Class to define data for extraction]
Class where the actual extraction is done:
[image: Class where the actual extraction is done]
      public PopulationData(String stateId, String totPopulation, String 
       schoolGoingPopuplation, String povertPopulation)
      {
         this.stateId = stateId;
         this.totPopulation = totPopulation;
         this.schoolGoingPopuplation = schoolGoingPopuplation;
         this.povertPopulation = povertPopulation;
      }

```
  public String getState()
  {
     return stateId;
  }

  public String getPopulation()
  {
     return totPopulation;
  }

  public String getSchool()
  {
     return schoolGoingPopuplation;
  }

  public String getPoverty()
  {
     return povertPopulation;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return this.stateId + " " + this.totPopulation + " " + 
     this.schoolGoingPopuplation + " " + this.povertPopulation;
  }
```

//this is the main class

```
         inFile = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileName));

        OutputStreamWriter outFile = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {

           String line = scanner.nextLine();

           String[] columns = line.split(" ");

           String sateId = columns[0];

           String totPopulation = columns[9]; 

           String schoolGoingPopuplation = columns[10]; //index out of bounds occured

           String povertPopulation = columns[11]; //index out of bounds occured

           PopulationData pd = new PopulationData(sateId, totPopulation, schoolGoingPopuplation, povertPopulation);
           data.add(pd);

           outFile.write(pd.toString()); 
        } 
        for(PopulationData pd : data){ 
           System.out.println(pd.toString()); 
        }       
     }
     catch(IOException except)
     {
        except.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Try putting code instead of the screenshots. Also array index means you are accessing the index that is out of your array size and non-static mean you are trying to access methods as they are static but they are not so you will be needing the instance of the class to access those.

Comment: What will be the best way to get this information by index and write it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

**Line 28,30,32**: are the fields in the file really separated by the tab character, and exactly one tab character? Doesn't look like it. My guess is it's using spaces, and your split is producing an array of exactly one column, which is the entire line. Given that you have a scanner instance you were probably intended to use that to read the fields with the `.nextInt()` and `.next()` methods.

**Line 37**: the `.add()` method is returning a boolean, which you are trying to write to the stream. You probably meant to write `outfile.write(pd.toString())`?

**Line 40**: you probably mean `System.out.println(pd.toString())`, what you have is effectively `PopulationDataManipulation.toString()` which doesn't work because it's an instance method and your main is static.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue on the writer and the print has been resolved. The only thing i'm figuring out is the indexing. What i'm trying to do with that is to split each line into an array so i can write just the information i want into a  new file file. I will then use that new file to calculate the percentage.

Comment: The split isn't working because you're trying to split a line that is delimited by spaces using the tab character. "01 00180 Auburn School District".split("\t") produces an array of one element ["01 00180 Auburn School District"]. You could do this with your scanner, eg: int col1 = scanner.nextInt(); int col2 = scanner.nextInt(); or you could use the fact that there are fixed width columns and grab it by substring, eg: String name = line.substring(10, 80).trim(); or you could match the whole thing with a regex ex Pattern.compile("\\d+ \\d+ ...") but imho split is the wrong approach here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg for the support. The substring method worked.